# How can my bot delete the /command messages sent to it in the group?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

First off let me start out by saying that I am not a programmer.

i need some help getting the following code to delete the /command sent to the bot from the group chat.

Not a programmer and put the following code together with examples i found.

Thanks

---

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram import (ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove)
import logging
import time

updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                     level=logging.INFO)

def start(bot, update):
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Where would you like to go?")
start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

### lions_park
def lions_park(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='<b>lions park</b> <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=49.266137,-122.780679"> Take Me There! </a>', parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
lions_park_handler = CommandHandler('lions_park', lions_park)
dispatcher.add_handler(lions_park_handler)

### frog_gym
def frog_gym(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='<b>frog gym</b> <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=49.299372,-122.760475"> Take Me There! </a>', parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
frog_gym_handler = CommandHandler('frog_gym', frog_gym)
dispatcher.add_handler(frog_gym_handler)

### bee_house
def bee_house(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='<b>bee house</b> <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=49.286018,-122.784835"> Take Me There! </a>', parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
bee_house_handler = CommandHandler('bee_house', bee_house)
dispatcher.add_handler(bee_house_handler)

updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please shorten your description and remove all information not directly related to your problem.  We do not care about your community meetups etc, but only what your code ought to do and what the problem is...

Comment: Thanks for removing all the unnecessary information. Unfortunately, I still do not quite understand your problem. Does the bot receive a string with a  leading `/command` substring from the users which you want to remove?

Comment: when users in the group call a command, everyone else in the group can see it and some confused users click on the command again in the group chat and the bot posts the results again.  Sometimes in a group of 500 this can happen a few times and fill up the screen.  I am hoping to have the bot delete the post from the user with the /command so no one accidentally sends the command again.